# Angular2 - Waiting for observable to return with data

Tags: angular

Angular2 templates seem to be fine with waiting for a list to return from an observable like this:

```
 <li *ngFor="let product of products">
       {{product.DisplayProductName}}
 </li>
...
export class PublicProductListComponent  {
    errorMessage: string;
    products: Products[];
    mode = 'Observable';

    constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

    ngOnInit() { this.getPublicProducts(); }

    getPublicProducts() {
        this.productService.getPublic()
            .subscribe(
            products => this.products = products,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

But when I tried to do the same thing with an object (`userDash`), I got errors saying the object was undefined because it wasn't waiting for the subscription to find data:

```
<li *ngFor="let prod of userDash.OwnedProducts">
    {{prod.DisplayProductName}}
</li>
...
export class OwnedProductListComponent {
    errorMessage: string;
    userDash: UserDashboard;
    mode = 'Observable';

    constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

    ngOnInit() { this.getUserDashboard(); }

    getUserDashboard() {
        this.userService.getUserDashboard()
            .subscribe(
            dashboard => this.userDash = dashboard,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

}
```

Doing a null/undefined check seems to work but I can't figure out if it's the most angular way to do it.

```
<ul *ngIf="userDash">
   <li *ngFor="let dash of userDash.OwnedProducts">
      {{dash.DisplayProductName}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

I'm still brand new trying to learn this pattern, so please forgive my ignorance.

EDIT --- Here's the code for `getUserDashboard()`

```
getUserDashboard(): Observable<UserDashboard> {

       return this.http.get(siteSettings.apiURL + "user/" + this.authService.getClientID() + "/dashboard", this.authService.getAuthorizationHeaders())
            .map(function (res: Response) {
                let body = res.json();
                return body;                
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);            
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your userService.getUserDashboard() code?

Comment: It's now available

Comment: Try to use async pipe. <li *ngFor="let dash of userDash.OwnedProducts | async">

Comment: Note that the `[angularjs]` tag is only for questions regarding AngularJS 1.x, not for Angular 2.

Comment: rook - nope, I already tried that,  @Mike  ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating the object in the constructor.

In the OwnedProductListComponent.ts

```
constructor(private userService: UserService) { 
    this.userDash = new UserDashboard();
}
```

In the UserDashboard Model class

```
export class UserDashboard{
    constructor() {
        this.OwnedProducts = new Products()
    }
}
```

Comment: Derp, duh... I had to manipulate my typescript model to handle an empty constructor but this worked.  So obvious, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think angular waits for the observable in either cases. I think that *ngFor just supports to loop over undefined, while in the second case, resolving userDash.OwnedProducts throws a JS error before starting to loop.

This works also:

```
<li *ngFor="let product of undefined">{{product}}</li>
```

Check this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/hvvJcz5IHCYscF3N3XtC?p=preview

[edit]

to fix your issue either use an async pipe as @rook suggested(you have to use *ngFor over an `Observable<Array<T>>` instead of `Array<T>`).

A detailed example is here:
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

or just initialize your data.